# How do I unit test Service Bus SendAsync method properly?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, azureservicebus

When running the unit test for Azure Service Bus method SendAsync I get the following exception on the line `_queueClient.Verify()`:

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once,  but was never performed: x => x.SendAsync({MessageId:})

This is my unit test:

```cs
public CustomerSendMsg(){ } //ctor

public async Task ShouldSendMessage()
{
    var _queueClient = new Mock<IQueueClient>();
    var _sut = new Publisher(_queueClient.Object);

    var customer = new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Doe"
    };

    _queueClient.Setup(t => t.SendAsync(It.IsAny<Message>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask).Verifiable();
    
    await _sut.SendMessageAsync(customer);
    
    var messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(customer);
    var msg = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
    
    _queueClient.Verify(t = > t.SendAsync(msg));
}
```

This is SendMessageAsync method from the Publisher class:

```cs
public async Task SendMessageAsync<T>(T obj)
{
    var messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
    var msg = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
    await _queueClient.SendAsync(msg);
}
```

Do you have any idea how can I make this unit test work?

Comment: I think the problem is that Moq checks if the two variables refer to the same objects. But the really big problem is you just copied the code from the method under test into your assert section. If this code has an error, you will never find it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new message object which wouldn't work because the references are different - you could decode the [`body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.body?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_Message_Body) property from the `Message` class and verify the customer object's properties.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing an object comparison (which is what Moq is doing), you can do the verification that the object being passed to the method has specific properties of the object using `It.Is<T>`.

```
_queueClient.Verify(t = > t.SendAsync(It.Is<byte[]>(x => x.Body == Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Tests for reference:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/tests/Sender/SenderTests.cs

```
       var mock = new Mock<ServiceBusSender>("fake", 
       ServiceBusTestUtilities.CreateMockConnection().Object, new 
        ServiceBusSenderOptions())
        {
            CallBase = true
        };
        mock
           .Setup(m => m.SendMessagesAsync(
               It.Is<IEnumerable<ServiceBusMessage>>(value => value.Count() == 1),
               It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
           .Returns(Task.CompletedTask)
           .Verifiable("The single send should delegate to the list send.");

        await mock.Object.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage());
```